# What is the best way to output Unicode to console?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++17, visual-studio-2019, wstring

I am working with C++17 in Visual Studio 2019. I have read a fair bit about encodings but I am still not very comfortable with them. I want to output UNICODE characters to screen. For that, I am using the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

std::wstring symbol{ L"♚" };

_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
std::wcout << symbol; //This works fine
std::cout << "Hello"; //This gives "Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: buffer_size % 2 == 0"
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), O_TEXT); //Need this to make std::cout work normally
std::cout << "World"; //This works fine
```

So I could do setmode to _O_WTEXT and then back to O_TEXT everytime I need to output the std::wstring. However, I am worried this may be an inefficient way to do things. Is there a better way to do it? I have read about something called native widechar support in C++ but I found it hard to understand. Could anyone illuminate me?

**EDIT**

To add to the above, using `_setmode(_fileno(stdout),_O_U16TEXT)` leads to the same behaviour as described above when trying to use `std::cout` without setting the mode back. If I use `_setmode(_fileno(stdout),_O_U8TEXT)` instead, my code fails to compile and gives errors `'symbol': redefinition, different basic types` and `'<<': illegal for class` when using `std::cout` on `std::string symbol = <insert any of the possibilities I tried in the snippet below>`.

I have been suggested to use a UTF-8 `std::string` to be able to use `std::cout` and that way avoid having to switch to wide mode. Could anyone give me a hand on how to achieve this? I have tried

```
std::string symbol = "\u265A"; //using std::cout gives "?" and triggers warning *
std::string symbol = "♚"; //Same as above

std::string symbol = u8"\u265A"; //using std::cout gives "ÔÖÜ"
std::string symbol = u8"♚"; //Same as above
```

*`Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4566   character represented by universal-character-name '\u265A' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)`

I have read it may be possible to convert from `std::wstring` to UTF-8 `std::string` using WideCharToMultiByte() from the header `<Windows.h>`. Would that work? Could anyone offer any help?

Comment: BTW, unicode is unrelated to wchar/char, you can use utf-8 to display unicode.

Comment: Yes you have to switch back and forth. Or you can consistently use `wcout` which works with ASCII, example `std::wcout << "Hello"`. If working with Windows 8 or higher, you can switch to using UTF8 for output, but you still need UTF16 for input.

Comment: With UTF-8 (i.e. codepage 65001), the CRT + console combination is still less than perfect, even in Windows 10. It may occasionally flush only part of a UTF-8 sequence in a write, which the console will decode as the replacement character, U+FFFD. The best results with the console are still with UTF-16 and the console's wide-character API. Certainly that's true for input. The console does not support reading non-ASCII characters as UTF-8.

Comment: FYI, you should do an `fflush` of a high-level `FILE` stream before switching the mode of its low-level fd.

Comment: @ErykSun Thank you for commenting. What do you mean with console's wide-character API? Is that the mode setting I describe in the question? I don't know what you mean in the last comment. Why should I do that and what does ```fflush``` mean? What is "fd"?

Comment: The C runtime `_write` function switches to calling [`WriteConsoleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) (in the wide-character console API) instead of `WriteFile` if the native file handle that wraps the fd (file descriptor) is a console file and the fd is in wide-character mode.

Comment: @ErykSun I am not experienced enough to understand what that means. Do you suggest there is a problem with my code? What do you suggest me to do exactly?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I suggest you could convert the string to UTF-8 and write that to std::cout. The standard streams aren't very good for wide characters.Otherwise, you need to switch back and forth.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Please see this new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61196799/how-can-i-convert-a-stdwstring-to-a-utf-8-stdstring) following up on how to convert from std::wstring to a utf-8 std::string.

Comment: This should just work: `std::cout << "\u265A";` (and it does on my machine). In fact, so does this: `std::cout << "♚"`. Perhaps this is an issue with the configuration of your terminal emulator?

Comment: "...cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)". You could try changing the code page with this: `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);`. Then try: `std::cout << "\u265A";`

Comment: @IndianaKernick That solved it! Thank you so much. You can post an answer if you want the bounty. Writing ```std::cout << "\u265A"``` and ```std::cout << "♚"``` still print ```?``` but writing ```std::cout << "u8\u265A``` and ```std::cout << u8"♚"``` now work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the error message. "...cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)". So the code page needs to be changed. The [code page identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) for UTF-8 is 65001. To change the code page, use [`SetConsoleOutputCP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp).