# How can I convert a std::wstring to a utf-8 std::string?

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding, c++17, wstring

I would like to print single Unicode characters to screen. I figured how to do it using `std::wstring`, as I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063497/what-is-the-best-way-to-output-a-stdwstring-to-console). However, I would like to be able to use `std::cout` consistently throughout my program (without need to switch to `std::wcout`). Therefore, I am trying to convert from `std::wstring` to utf-8 `std::string`. All the posts asking about this conversion that I have read describe the usage of the header `<codecvt>`. However, it was [deprecated](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html) in C++17 and gives the run-time error
`'std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t,1114111,0>,wchar_t,std::allocator<wchar_t>,std::allocator<char>>::to_bytes': warning STL4017: std::wbuffer_convert, std::wstring_convert, and the <codecvt> header (containing std::codecvt_mode, std::codecvt_utf8, std::codecvt_utf16, and std::codecvt_utf8_utf16) are deprecated in C++17. (The std::codecvt class template is NOT deprecated.) The C++ Standard doesn't provide equivalent non-deprecated functionality; consider using MultiByteToWideChar() and WideCharToMultiByte() from <Windows.h> instead. You can define _SILENCE_CXX17_CODECVT_HEADER_DEPRECATION_WARNING or _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning.` if you try to use any of its functionality.

This deprecation means we cannot any longer use accepted answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358870/convert-wstring-to-string-encoded-in-utf-8), which suggests doing

```
#include <codecvt>
// convert wstring to UTF-8 string
std::string wstring_to_utf8 (const std::wstring& str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.to_bytes(str);
}
```

or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string?noredirect=1&lq=1), which also relies on using codecvt.

The error I quoted above suggests using `WideCharToMultiByte()` from the header `<Windows.h>`. However, I am not an expert on encodings and I need some help to figure out how to use this. Could someone offer any help, or describe any alternate approaches?

Comment: "*This deprecation means we cannot any longer use accepted answers such as this*" Deprecated does not mean "removed" or "unavailable". You can keep using it if you like. "*gives the run-time error*" That's a warning, not an error. And you can turn it off.

Comment: My code fails to build and that message appears as an error in the log so no, it is not just a warning.

Comment: @NicolBolas Also, how does my question have an answer on that question "Deprecated header <codecvt> replacement?". My question is not about codecvt but about converting from wstring to string. The user in that question wants to convert from utf-8 to utf-16, and the answers suggest they implement it themselves. My question asks for help on how to convert wstring to string using WideCharToMultiByte from Windows.h, or any alternative approaches.

Comment: "*My question is not about codecvt but about converting from wstring to string.*" `<codecvt>` is how you would do that conversion, and you would be using it if it weren't deprecated (and you could still be using it if you do what the warning message said to do). So you do want a replacement for the deprecated header.

Comment: @NicolBolas As I said, the answers to that question suggest the OP to implement the desired conversion by themselves. If you like, in this question I am building up on that and asking about how to use WideCharToMultiByte from Windows.h to convert from wstring to string, or whether there are any alternative new approaches (its been 3 years since that question was posted). Please reopen my question and let other people have their input.